# Return JSON token from postman

Tags: php, json, jwt, postman, symfony4

I am implementing JWT into Symfony 4 project.

When I try following command using curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/login -d "
{\"email\":\"test2@mail.com\",\"password\":\"admin\"}"
```

It is generating the token. But When I try it using postman, I am getting `Token not found` error

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

In Postman, I am using following params:

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/login
METHOD: POST
HEADERS >> KEY: Content-Type VALUE: application/json
BODY >> x-www-form-urlencoded
email & password
```

Can anybody please help me how can I get token from postman?

Comment: try using `BODY >> raw` and plain json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause your request must be `json`.

You must send your data as `raw`. so in `BODY` tab select `raw` and place your plain json in it. see image:

[image]

Comment: thanks I got it. If I pass ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` what steps changes should I follow. Any idea?

Comment: @user1687891 your api just supports raw request so you must do it. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` posts your data like submiting form. you want do this json in php?

Comment: Yes I have a login form to submit.